# AjaxControlToolkit cannot be properly installed

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

When I am installing AjaxControlToolkit using nuGet from within Ms Visual Studio, I am getting the following errors:

```
PM> install-Package AjaxControlToolkit
Attempting to resolve dependency 'AjaxMin (≥ 4.97.4951.28483)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'HtmlAgilityPack (≥ 1.4.6)'.
'AjaxControlToolkit 7.0725' already installed.
The directory is not empty.

Successfully uninstalled 'AjaxMin 4.97.4951.28483'.
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'AjaxMin'.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-Package <<<<  AjaxControlToolkit
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],InvalidOperationException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId:NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,
 NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by:

1. Deleting `packages.config`
2. Reinstalling all of my NuGet packages.

If that fails, you can always:

1. Download the binaries from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/
2. Drop the DLL and PDB files into your `\bin\` folder.
3. Add them as references manually.